# FPS drops on Windows 8.1 Pro when idle

Tags: windows-8, graphics-card, windows-8.1, framerate

Hello I got this issue since I upgraded my Windows 8 to Windows 8.1. While I'm playing a game or watching a movie, if I do not move the mouse for like 30 seconds or so game fps drops to 20-30 from 120-300 also movies are starting to mini-freeze.

My graphic card is HD7850 2GB edition with 13.9 driver version.

Comment: have you checked/adjusted you power saving settings yet?  Have you disabled all 3rd party utilities and see how it acts?

Comment: sure that was first thing i've checked for make sure. im using a desktop computer with 700w psu and every power thing works on performance mode.

Comment: The graphic card driver model change sigificantly.  Have you installed all the system updates?  Microsoft fix a mouse lag bug recently.  Of course if you are going from 300 fps to 30 fps there is something major going on.